# swift 2.0 prepareForSegue not working

Tags: ios, swift, class, viewcontroller

I'm trying to use `prepareForSegue` in an app I am making. prepare forSegue has to pass a class to a separate view controller. Here is the code in `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "createPieceSegue" {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as DestinationViewController!

        svc.pieceBaseClass = myClass
    }
}
```

These are the superclasses that the first view controller inherits from:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate
```

And the destination view controller is inheriting from `UIViewController` only. The error I keep getting is: `UIViewController is not convertible to'DestinationViewController'` Thus I can't pass data between the two. What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you've not set the custom class of the destination VC in your storyboard. So it's just a UIViewController and not your subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use optional chaining. Did you make sure that DestinationViewController actually is a subclass of the UIViewController ?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "createPieceSegue" {
    if let svc = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationViewController {
        svc.pieceBaseClass = myClass
    }
}
```